# Set constraint of bar button item Swift?

Tags: swift, constraints

I'm programmatically adding a bar button item like this:

```
    let button = UIButton.init(type: .custom)
    button.setImage(UIImage(named: "Bar Chart Filled-50"), for: UIControlState.normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.statButtonPressed), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40)
    let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
    navItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton
```

I want it to be vertically centered in the page's navigation bar. How would I do such a thing programatically.

image: [image: img]

Comment: I would have thought it was already being centred vertically. If not, can you include an image?

Comment: added it, it might be because I have an empty prompt

Comment: Thanks for adding the screenshot. It makes me wonder if the problem might be that the column chart icon might not be centred in its frame, with a blank area at the top.

Comment: Check out what you see in the Debug View Hierarchy feature of Xcode. It's one of the buttons in the debug toolbar and looks like two overlapping rectangles. You'll be able to see the frames of each view.

Comment: FYI, you can add a *view* instead of -directly adding a- bar button and then add whatever you want in it.

Comment: @AhmadF I figured out how to add it in my storyboard, thanks